# Open-source Hexahedral meshing tools

Tags: software, mesh-generation, mesh, open-source

I'm looking for an **open-source** automatic meshing tool or library able to generate full or dominant **hexahedral mesh** starting from a provided arbitrary model i.e. a surface triangular mesh stored in STL file.

What I have found is snappyHexMesh embedded in OpenFOAM. Are there some other tools that fit my purpose?

Someone already asked a quite similar question [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/survey-on-automatic-structured-mesh-generation-tools) but it's a quite old answer. Has something new been released in the meanwhile?

Thank you

Comment: The answers from the question you link to are still current.

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangBangerth. Therefore, there are no other open-source tools besides OpenFoam. Am I wrong? Do you know if there are some open-source C++ libraries able to generate hexahedral mesh?

Comment: Just the ones mentioned in the post you link to.

Comment: Do that need your need sir ? https://gmsh.info/ Thanks